# How can I access items from ng-repeat inside child directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

so I'm trying to get the variables from an ng-repeat into a directive that is inside the ng-repeat. I can't seem to figure it out, I have been looking at a couple things '@' and '=' but I don't think I'm using them properly, can anyone give me a clear example of how to achieve this please, and thanks.

index.html

```
<li ng-repeat="item in menu">
     <div backImg="{{item.img}}" class="homeimg"></div>                        
</li>
```

directive.js

```
app.directive('backImg', function(){
    return function(scope, element, attrs){
        var url = attrs.backImg;
        scope: {
            backImg:'='  
        }
        /*
        element.css(
            //'background-image': 'url("/angular/my_first_project/v4/images/home_spiderman.jpg")'
            'background-color','yellow',
            "border", "1px solid orange"
        );
        */

        element.css("background", "yellow");
    };
});
```

Comment: first of all your directive definition is wrong. you should return an object with `link` and `scope` properties.

Answer (score 0):

As @Satpal mentioned, you have the scope defined with bi-directional data binding, so you need to not use interpolation for the attribute in the HTML. However, you also haven't declared the Directive properly (actually, it looks like invalid JavaScript).

```
app.directive('backImg', function(){
    return {
        scope: {
            backImg:'='  
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){
            var url = scope.backImg;

            /*
            element.css(
                //'background-image': 'url("/angular/my_first_project/v4/images/home_spiderman.jpg")'
                'background-color','yellow',
                "border", "1px solid orange"
            );
            */

            element.css("background", "yellow");
        }
    };
});
```

Also, you need to use the dashed version of attribute `back-img` in the HTML:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in menu">
    <div back-img="item.img" class="homeimg"></div>                        
</li>
```

Comment: hey this worked, thanks a lot for giving me a clear example. I don't understand why i had to change my directive name to back-img though, it doesn't match the directive's name how is it even connecting to it?